# Uniform bounded of Riemann-like sum and improper integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

For any $h>0$, suppose $\{(y_i,y_{i+1}]\mid i\in \mathbb{Z}\}$ be a uniform partition of $\mathbb{R}$ with mesh size $h$. I am considering under what condition for a continuous transition density function $p(h,x,y)$ of a stochastic process, we can have
$$\sum_i p(h,x,\xi)h^3\le Mh^\alpha$$ 
uniformly in $h,x$. Let's take Gaussian density function as an example.

That is, given the Gaussian density function
$$p(h,x,y)=\frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{h}}e^{-\frac{(x-y)^2}{2h}},$$
I am considering the following two questions:

1. Whether there exists $M,h_0>0$ independent of $x$, such that  $h\in (0,h_0)$, we have
   $$\sum_i p(h,x,\xi_i)h^3\le Mh^\alpha,\tag{1}$$ for some $\alpha>0$.
2. Whether the Riemann-like sum can be approximated by a corresponding improper integral in the sense that for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists $h_0$ independent of $x$, such that for any $0<h<h_0,x\in \mathbb{R}$, we have
   $$|\sum_i p(h,x,\xi_i)h- \int_\mathbb{R}p(h,x,y)\,dy|<\epsilon .\tag{2}$$

Here $\xi_i\in (y_i,y_{i+1})$ satisfies $p(h,x,\xi_i)=\sup_{y\in [y_i,y_{i+1}]}p(h,x,y)$.

---

I am really sorry that I edited the question. I added more background information so that I can express my original question in a clearer way.

Thanks for Kirvich Entracus's answer. Generalizing the idea in the answer, if 
$$p(h,x,y)\le \dfrac{M}{\sqrt{h}}$$
uniformly and such that for fixed $h$, there exists $\delta(h)>0$, such that  for any fixed $x$, if $|y-x|>\delta(h)$, we have $p(h,x,y)$ decreases when $|y-x|$increases, 
then we can have 
$$\sum_i p(h,x,\xi_i)h\le \dfrac{M}{\sqrt{h}} \delta(h)+1$$
uniformly for small $h$ by comparing it with the improper integral.

Comment: $v(\eta_i)$ doesn't really make sense for an L^2 function. Do you want to make further assumptions on $v?$

Comment: Also, if  x=y you can see that p is not uniformly bounded as you claimed.

Comment: @zhw. I know $p$ is not uniformly bounded, but $hp$ is, like I said in the question.

Comment: @zhw. For regularity of $v$, basically it can be as smooth as you want.

Comment: Ah sorry on the p business, misread what you had.

Comment: What is a "uniform partition"? I know what a partition is, but not a uniform one. Also, do you take $h$ to be $\sup _i (y_{i+1} - y_i)$, or do you assume the points $(y_i)$ to be equally spaced?

Comment: @AlexM. Sorry, but uniform partition, I mean $(y_i)$ are equally spaced with distance $h$, and $\cup_i(y_i,y_{I+1})=\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Don't you want $\sqrt {2\pi}$ instead of $2\pi?$ (Not that it matters, just wondering.)

Answer (score 2):

We may assume $y_k=kh$ $(k\in{\mathbb Z})$ and $0\leq x\leq h$. Then it is easy to see that
$$|x-x_k|\geq\bigl(|k|-1\bigr)h\qquad(k\ne0)\ .$$
It follows that
$$p(h,x,x_k)={1\over 2\pi\sqrt{h}}e^{-(x-x_k)^2/(2h)}\leq{1\over 2\pi\sqrt{h}}e^{-(|k|-1)^2h/2}\qquad(k\ne0)\ .$$
Summing over $k\in{\mathbb Z}$ and taking proper care of $k=0$ we therefore obtain
$$\sum_k p(h,x,x_k)\leq{1\over 2\pi\sqrt{h}}\bigl(2+\sum_k e^{-k^2 h/2}\bigr)={1\over 2\pi\sqrt{h}}\bigl(2+{1\over\sqrt{h}}\cdot\sqrt{h}\sum_k e^{-(k\sqrt{h})^2/2}\bigr)\ .$$
There is an $h_0>0$ such that
$$2\sqrt{h}<1,\qquad \bigl(\sqrt{2\pi}\sim\bigr)\  \sqrt{h}\sum_k e^{-(k\sqrt{h})^2/2}<3\qquad(0<h<h_0)\ .$$
It follows that
$$\sum_k p(h,x,x_k)\leq{2\over \pi h}\qquad(0<h<h_0)\ ,$$
so that you obtain the desired estimate with $\alpha=2$, $M={2\over\pi}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I am sorry that I edited my question. I really appreciate your help and I have upvoted your answer for your elegant estimate and great effort.

Answer (score 1):

Looks not that complicated, if I understood the statements correctly.

For simplicity let me set $x=0$, $y_0=0$.

$i\geq 0\,\, \sum_{i\geq 0} p(h,0,\xi _i)h\leq \frac{h^\frac{1}{2}}{2\pi}+ \sum_{i\geq 0} q(h,0,\xi_i)h\leq\frac{h^\frac{1}{2}}{2\pi}+\int _{y\geq0}p(h,0,y)dy\leq \frac{h^\frac{1}{2}}{2\pi}+\frac{1}{2}\,\,\, where\,\, q(h,0,\xi_i)=inf\{p(h,0,y)|y\in (y_i,y_{i+1}]\}
\\
i<0\,\, \sum_{i< 0} p(h,0,\xi _i)h\leq \frac{h^\frac{1}{2}}{2\pi}+ \sum_{i< 0} q(h,0,\xi_i)h\leq\frac{h^\frac{1}{2}}{2\pi}+\int _{y<0}p(h,0,y)dy\leq\frac{h^\frac{1}{2}}{2\pi}+\frac{1}{2}\,\,\, where\,\, q(h,0,\xi_i)=inf\{p(h,0,y)|y\in (y_i,y_{i+1}]\}$
So for some constant $C>0$

$\sum_ip(h,0,y)h\leq Ch^{\frac{1}{2}}+1
\\
\sum_ip(h,0,y)h^3\leq (Ch^{\frac{1}{2}}+1)h^2$

So we can choose $(Ch_0^{\frac{1}{2}}+1)$ for M and $\alpha=2$.

When $x$ is not zero, slight modifications conclude the same result.

Comment: To have $\sum_{i\geq 0} q(h,0,\xi_i)h\le \int _{y\geq0}p(h,0,y)dy$, do you use the function $p(h,x,y)$ is monotone in $y$? and how to get  $h^{\frac{1}{2}}$ in your expression?

Comment: Yes, $p(h,0,y)$ decreases as $|y|$ increases that inequality holds. $h^{\frac{1}{2}}$ comes from the first term of the each sum $\sum_{i\geq 0} p(h,0,\xi _i)h$ and $\sum_{i<0} p(h,0,\xi _i)h$. $p(h,0,\xi_0)=\frac{1}{2\pi h^{\frac{1}{2}}}$ and mutiply h. I don't know what oscillation you mean.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $f:\mathbb R \to [0,\infty)$ is even, decreasing on $[0,\infty),$ with $\int_{\mathbb R} f <\infty.$ Let $g$ be any translate of $f$ and let $c_i\in [(i-1)h,ih]$ for each $i\in \mathbb Z.$ Then

$$\tag 1 \int_{\mathbb R} g - 3f(0)h \le \sum_{i\in \mathbb Z} g(c_i)h \le \int_{\mathbb R} g + 3f(0)h.$$

This result answers your questions 1. and 2. in the affirmative: Your function $p(h,x,y),$ which we can think of as the $g$ in $(1),$ is the $x$ translate of $e^{-y^2/2h}/\sqrt {2\pi h},$ which we can think of at the $f$ above. The sum $\sum p(h,x,c_i)h$ is thus precisely the sum in $(1),$ hence is bounded above by $3/\sqrt {2\pi h} + 1$ for all $h>0.$ Thus the answer to 1. is yes, with $\alpha = 2$ (as others have noticed). For 2. we see

$$ |\sum_{i\in \mathbb Z} g(c_i)h - \int_{\mathbb R} g| \le 3f(0)h = 3\sqrt {h/2\pi}.$$

This gives a rate of vanishing on the order of $\sqrt h,$ so the answer to 2. is yes.

Proof of $(1)$: First observe that we have

$$\tag 2 2\sum_{k =1}^\infty f(kh)h \le \int_{\mathbb R} f \le 2\sum_{k =0}^\infty f(kh) h.$$

You prove this by first looking at $[0,\infty),$ where $f$ is decreasing, then do what you do when you prove the integral test of calculus. (It's just a matter of staring down some rectangles.) Then use the fact that $f$ is even; that's where the factor of $2$ comes from.

Fix $x\in \mathbb R$ and set $g(y) = f(y-x).$ Put $I_{k} =[(k-1)h, kh], k \in \mathbb Z.$ Now $x\in I_{k_0}$ for some $k_0.$ On $I_{k_0},$ $g\le f(0).$ On $I_{k_0+1}$ we also have $g\le f(0).$ On $I_{k_0+2}$ we have $g\le f(h),$ on $I_{k_0+3}$ we have $g\le f(2h),$ and so on down the line. The analogous estimates hold to the left of $I_{k_0}.$ Therefore

$$\sum_{i\in \mathbb Z} g(c_i)h  \le 3f(0)h + 2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}f(kh)h \le 3f(0)h+ \int_{\mathbb R} f,$$

where we have used $(2).$ Because $\int_{\mathbb R} f = \int_{\mathbb R} g,$ we have the right hand inequality in $(1).$

For the left hand inequality in $(1),$ we have $g\ge f(h)$ on $I_{k_0},$ $g\ge f(2h)$ on $I_{k_0+1},$ $g\ge f(3h),$ and so on. The analogous estimates hold on the intervals to the left of $I_{k_0}.$ Therefore

$$ f(h)h + 2\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}f(kh)h \le \sum_{i\in \mathbb Z} g(c_i)h .$$

Now add $2f(0)h + f(h)h$ to both sides and use $(2).$ We get

$$\int_{\mathbb R} f  \le 2\sum_{k =0}^\infty f(kh)\cdot h \le 2f(0)h + f(h)h + \sum_{i\in \mathbb Z} g(c_i)h \le 3f(0)h + \sum_{i\in \mathbb Z} g(c_i)h.$$

This gives what we want, again using $\int_{\mathbb R} f = \int_{\mathbb R} g.$